# Drawing Cube-Connected Cycles graph with TikZ, Any useful package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

What is the best way to draw 3D-like graphs? In particular, I am trying to find a good method to draw *Cube-Connected Cycles graph CCC* with TikZ? CCC3 is depicted below.

Is there any package that provides an extensive list of common graphs? I know `tkz-berge` does provide some classic graphs but it is not sufficient. Another graph that I have in mind, for example, is *de Bruijn graph*.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a package that helps to draw this graph, but it's no so difficult to do it directly with tikz. You only need a lot of `\foreach` commands to avoid repeating code.

This could be a starting point:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}   % for 'canvas is ...' option in the scope
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % calculates coordinates

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[z={(0.5cm,0.5cm)}]
  % dimensions
  \def\l{4}    % cube edges lenght
  \def\r{1}    % circles radii
  \def\d{0.05} % dots radii
  % coordinates and circles
  \foreach\y in {1,2} \foreach\i in {1,...,4}
  {%
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=\y*\l,rotate=90*\i-45]
      \coordinate (\y-\i-0) at ({0.5*sqrt(2)*\l},0);
      \foreach\j in {1,2,3}
      {%
        \coordinate(\y-\i-\j) at ($(\y-\i-0)+(135*\j-270:\r)$);
        %\node[above] at (\y-\i-\j) {\small\y-\i-\j}; % <-- uncomment to see the
      }                                               %     coordinates names
      \draw (\y-\i-0) circle (\r);
    \end{scope}
  }
  % lines
  \foreach\i in {1,...,4}
  {% vertical lines:
    \draw[fill] (1-\i-2) circle (\d) -- (2-\i-2) circle (\d);
    \foreach\j in {1,2}
    {% horizontal lines:
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\ii{Mod(\i,4)+1}
      \draw[fill] (\j-\i-3) circle (\d) -- (\j-\ii-1) circle (\d);
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]